# What is the unit of distance parameter in Google Takeout Location history JSON files?

Tags: google-location-services

Here's a snippet from Google Takeout Location history file.
[image]

I'm supposing that distance provided by Google is in meters. So when I divide it by 1000, I get 5.69 km. So far so good.
But when I browse to this trip from Google timeline, it shows me the distance 6.3 km. Not sure why there is this deviation.

May be its because Google timeline recalculates the distance with different route? Or may be the distance provided by Google is not in meters?

This behavior is observed for all my trips.

Comment: Could the distance value be the "as-the-crow-flies" distance between the start and end locations (maybe even including some waypoints, but essentially a geometric calculation)? Whereas in Google timeline, maybe Google maps it onto roads and gives the route distance?

Comment: I'm seeing the same kind of discrepancy. Is there any way to get the actual, e.g., distance driven, along roads, which matches what Google Maps Timeline shows? I even tried adding in all the `waypoints`